# Adding a gap between widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

How do I get a gap in between the two buttons, generate and clear?

Comment: You can use padding. What geometry manager are you using. `grid()` or `pack()`?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech  I am using grid()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add space between two widgets placed in grid in tkinter ~ python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555194/how-to-add-space-between-two-widgets-placed-in-grid-in-tkinter-python)

Comment: The title is very specific and descriptive of the actual problem!

Comment: Have you investigated and experimented with the various options to `grid`? There  are multiple options, some of which are specifically for what you're asking. Also, if you're asking for coding help, you're less likely to get downvoted and more likely to get helped if you provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are only looking to have padding between the 2 buttons you can use `pady = (0,5)` in your `grid()` manager for your Generate button. If you want to add space between all 3 `pady = (5,5)` or `pady = 5`.

There are 2 ways you can provide a number/numbers to your `padx` or `pady`. You can use just a number like `pady = 5` and this would do both the top and bottom padding but if you want to specifically pad just one side you can provide a tuple like this `pady = (0,5)` and this would just pad the bottom of the widget.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root, width = 25).grid(row=0, column=0)

tk.Button(root, text = "Generate").grid(row=1, column=0, pady = (5,5))
tk.Button(root, text = "clear").grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

And here is an example for just space between the buttons:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root, width = 25).grid(row=0, column=0)

tk.Button(root, text = "Generate").grid(row=1, column=0, pady = (0,5))
tk.Button(root, text = "clear").grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]