# Don't understand grid() in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I know this is a bit of a broad question. I'm just starting out with Python and Tkinter and I'm building my first app. I have a few widgets done and a few more on the way but I can't seem to place them the way I want at all. Here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk
import time
from threading import Thread
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master

def update_timeText():
    current = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    seconds = time.strftime(":%S")
    currentDate=time.strftime("%a %e %B, %Y")
    timeText1.configure(text=current, fg='white', background='black')
    timeText1.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='NW', padx=15, pady=15)
    timeText2.configure(text=seconds, fg='white', background='black')
    timeText2.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=17, sticky='NW')
    Date.configure(text=currentDate, fg='white', background='black')
    Date.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='NW', padx=20, pady=124, rowspan=2)  
    root.after(1000, update_timeText)

def update_Weather():
    temperature=int(13)
    picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(picturePNG)
    weatherIcon.configure(image=picture, background='black')
    weatherIcon.grid(column=5, sticky='ne')
    weatherTemperature.configure(text=temperature, fg='white', background='black')
    weatherTemperature.grid(column=6, sticky='ne')
    root.after(100000, update_Weather)

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.title('Smart Mirror')
timeText1 = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Opinio", 90, "bold"))
timeText2 = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Opinio", 45, "bold"))
weatherTemperature=tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Roboto Condensed", 80))
weatherIcon=tk.Label(root, image="")
Thread(target=update_Weather).start()
Thread(target=update_timeText).start()
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I managed to get after hours of messing with the grid and Googling:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsoxO.png)

What I'm trying to get:
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X20LM.png)

I just can't seem to make any space horizontally inbetween the widgets. I know I'm asking for a lot but if someone could explain grid a bit instead of just posting an answer I'd be really grateful, since I've read a lot of information about it online and can't seem to get the gist of it at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add space between two widgets placed in grid in tkinter ~ python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555194/how-to-add-space-between-two-widgets-placed-in-grid-in-tkinter-python)

Comment: Take a look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: I already looked at that website many times but I don't understand it quite well. What I'm looking for is more along the line of grid() for dummies.

Comment: Since you're asking about `grid`, and not about threads or urllib or the other things in this code, I recommend you reduce this code down to a [mcve] that has only the grid code, and enough other code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry i posted a question once before and i was asked to include everything so i thought i should do the same here, I've cleaned it up as much as possible while trying to keep the base functionality.

Comment: Just add `row=0` when you grid your `weatherIcon` and `weatherTemperature` in `update_Weather`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create widgets as slaves to `root` instead of as slaves to the class `Window()`. This is confusing and makes the class dependant on that the main program creates some of the widgets that the `Window()` object will later configure.

Assign `row` when you grid widgets, as @Henry Yik comments.

Here is an example of how I would place the widgets:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master
        self.configure(bg='thistle')    # To see where self is
        self.pack(expand=True, fill='both', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # Which column should change
                                            # when window size changes

        Date = tk.Label(self, text='19:38:25', fg='white', bg='black',
                                      font='-size 70')
        Date.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='NW', padx=20, pady=70, rowspan=2)  

        picture = tk.PhotoImage(file='sun.png')
        weatherIcon = tk.Label(self, image=picture, bg='black')
        weatherIcon.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky='NE')
        weatherIcon.image = picture     # Save a reference to the picture

        weatherTemperature = tk.Label(self, text='4°C', fg='white', bg='black',
                                      font='-size 70')
        weatherTemperature.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky='NE')

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background='tan')    # To see where root is
root.geometry('900x300')

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Does this explain any better?

Comment: I didnt really use your code here but it did help me a lot, and i managed to figure it out with it. Thanks a bunch.