# How can I add space between buton and label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, window, sticky

My problem is space between button and entry label which look awful for me at this moment. Trying with padx doesn't work, cuz it don't want to move. I already used columnspan for buttons and here's a problem, that I can't use padx to make space between "No" button and left place for writing "new word". Is there any way to change it?

Can I use  "sticky" command to connect it to label above this button? Is there anything I can do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vK3K.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089851/tkinter-username-password-in-centre-of-the-screen/74181452#74181452

Answer (score 0):

This question is very minimal, with no code to work with I am unsure on what you have already done however this may help!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39555320/17685290

When you pack the widget you can use

```
self.a_button = Button(root, text="A Button") 
self.a_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Using padx and pady you can add padding to the outer side of the button and alternatively if you want to increase the size of the button you can add inner padding using ipadx and ipady.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set  the `height` and `width` in addition to the `padx` and `pady:

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post snippets directly as text and not as images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question