# tkinter Username + Password in centre of the screen

Tags: python, tkinter, centering

Password needs to packed below username and this should be able to be done with any number of widgets

```
from tkinter import *

Master = Tk()
Master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

Frame = Frame(Master)
Frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")

UsernameLabel = Label(Frame, text = "Username").pack(side = "left")
UsernameEntry = Entry(Frame).pack(side = "right")

PasswordLabel = Label(Frame, text = "Password").pack(side = "left")
PasswordEntry = Entry(Frame).pack(side = "right")

Master.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make it so in the centre of the screen it looks like this.

Username:

Password:
.

.

.

etc...

But I have been looking for answers and I cannot find any. Does anyone have a solution.

Comment: If you're trying to align widgets in columns, `grid` is easier to use than `pack`. Have you tried using `grid`?

Answer (score 2):

Is this is what you want?

```
from tkinter import *

Master = Tk()
#Master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

Frame = Frame(Master)
Frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")

email_label = Label(Frame, text="Username:")
email_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

email_entry = Entry(Frame)
email_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
email_entry.focus()

password_label = Label(Frame, text="Password:")
password_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

password_entry = Entry(Frame)
password_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
 
Master.mainloop()
```

Result output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, all in one piece or side by side. So use the `grid` instead of `pack` widgets.

```
from tkinter import *


Master = Tk()
#Master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

Frame = Frame(Master)
Frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")

email_label = Label(Frame, text="Username:").grid(row=0)
email_entry = Entry(Frame)
email_entry.grid(row=0, column=1) 
email_entry.focus()

password_label = Label(Frame, text="Password:").grid(row=1)
password_entry = Entry(Frame)
password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
 
Master.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]